# Unable to run Ofbiz POS

Tags: java, ofbiz

I have installed Ofbiz using `ant load-demo start` and its working fine. I can start http://localhost:8080/catalog and http://localhost:8080/ecommerce but when I am going to start the pos it is not starting. When I use `java -jar ofbiz.jar -pos` its gives me the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.ofbiz.base.start.StartupException: Couldn't not f
etch config instance
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:202)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:127)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot load configuration properties : org/ofbiz
/base/start/-pos.properties
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Config.getPropertiesFile(Config.java:229)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Config.readConfig(Config.java:297)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Config.getInstance(Config.java:58)
        at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:200)
        ... 1 more
```

When I use `ant start-pos` or `java -jar ofbiz.jar pos` splash screen is coming but it is getting stuck there as

[image: POS]

Answer (score 1):

Ofbiz does not package POS module by default. The POS module need to be downloaded separately [Ofbiz POS](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ofbiz/branches/release14.12/specialpurpose/pos/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue, which version of ofbiz are you using?

There is a ticket in the Ofbiz's Jira that exposes the same issue with the version *13.* *
Apparently they remove the POS functionality in this version, and you have to do some workarounds to make this working in this version.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-6541

Answer (score 0):

To complete the above answer, here is an excerpt of [the OFBIz POS official documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/POS+System)

With  [OFBIZ-7804](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-7804) The POS has been pushed in  [OFBiz Attic](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Attic#OFBizAttic-POS).

The last released version with the POS available was R12.04.06. It's though still available in the R14.12 and 15.12 non released branches. It'll not be available with the R16 release and further. All the POS official documentation is reliable and usable before revision 1754402